# Azure AD Multitenant WebApi Bearer Authorization Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I'm currently working on an ASP.net MVC and Web API project with AAD single sign on. The current problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to configure the authorization for the WebAPI. This is my current way I've tried but it doesn't work.

```
 
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
...
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                        new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                        {
                            Tenant = "common",
                            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                            {
                                ValidAudience = audience,
                                ValidateIssuer = false
```

```
                        }              });
```

...}

And I fetch the access token trough postman token predefined token request and that works.

[postman token request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O0gw.png)

When I call the WebAPI (Header: Authorization -> Bearer )I got the following exception back:

```
{
    "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

Do I have to prepare the token request, the API header, or the configuration?

BG,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample about [Building a multi-tenant web API secured by Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-multitenant-windows-store/). You could download it and follow the steps it provided to configure it.

The application uses the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) to obtain a JWT access token through the OAuth 2.0 protocol. The access token is sent to the web API to authenticate the user. The web API project demonstrates how to structure your services for being accessed by users coming from multiple Azure AD tenants.

As you want to login multiple tenants, you need to go to the app registered and click `Manifest` option set `availableToOtherTenants` to `true`.
[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://shweta612.wordpress.com/2017/05/17/creating-multi-tenant-azure-ad-authenticated-web-api-manual-jwt-authentication/).

Comment: Yeah, I know all these samples, I already set it to true but my problem is the token validation. How can I check why the token isn't a valid one?

Or should I use another Postman Request Token call?

I used the token in the anonymous call of my API for calling users and it works (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users)